# Not able to post status using social auth in twitter and facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter, python-social-auth, socialauth

When trying to update status in facebook and twitter using social auth, getting below exception. Any idea how to fix it out?

> 20:31:56,559 INFO  [stdout] (default task-7) Exception occured in call back method  ::::: org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: Status not updated. Return Status code :403

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly format the error - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit to provide more detail and code sample in order to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching more, i was able to resolve this issue.

We need to add proper call back url and we need to give write permission in the twitter developer console